# How can I apply a matrix transform to each row of a NumPy array efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a 2d NumPy ndarray, like so:

```
[[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ],
 [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
 [ 8, 9, 10, 11 ]]
```

Conceptually speaking, what I want to do is this:

```
For each row:
    Transpose the row
    Multiply the transposed row by a transformation matrix
    Transpose the result
    Store the result in the original ndarray, overwriting the original row data
```

I have an *extremely* slow, brute-force method which functionally achieves this:

```
import numpy as np
transform_matrix = np.matrix( /* 4x4 matrix setup clipped for brevity */ )
for i, row in enumerate( data ):
    tr = row.reshape( ( 4, 1 ) )
    new_row = np.dot( transform_matrix, tr )
    data[i] = new_row.reshape( ( 1, 4 ) )
```

However, this seems like the sort of operation that NumPy should do well with.  I assume that - as someone new to NumPy - I'm just missing something fundamental in the documentation.  Any pointers?

Note that if it's faster to create a new ndarray rather than edit it in-place, that can work for what I'm doing, too; speed of the operation is the primary concern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lengthy series of operations you want to perform is equivalent to the following:

```
data[:] = data.dot(transform_matrix.T)
```

or using a new array instead of modifying the original, which should be a bit faster:

```
data.dot(transform_matrix.T)
```

Here's the explanation:

```
For each row:
    Transpose the row
```

Equivalent to transposing the matrix and then going over the columns.

```
    Multiply the transposed row by a transformation matrix
```

Left-multiplying each column of a matrix by a second matrix is equivalent to left-multiplying the whole thing by the second matrix. At this point, what you have is `transform_matrix.dot(data.T)`

```
    Transpose the result
```

One of the basic properties of matrix transposes is that `transform_matrix.dot(data.T).T` is equivalent to `data.dot(transform_matrix.T)`.

```
    Store the result in the original ndarray, overwriting the original row data
```

The slice assignment does this.

Comment: the slice is redundant here, I think

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for walking through the explanation as well - it was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you need [transpose operator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T):

```
>>> np.random.seed(11)
>>> transform_matrix = np.random.randint(1, 10, (4,4))
>>> np.dot(transform_matrix, data.T).T
matrix([[ 24,  24,  17,  37],
        [ 76, 108,  61, 137],
        [128, 192, 105, 237]])
```

or equivalently, as (A*B).T = (B.T * A.T):

```
>>> np.dot(data, transform_matrix.T)
```

Comment: +1 for pointing to matrix algebra - this is not a programming issue but a lack of understanding of matrix algebra